# Generate and download excel file

Tags: java, excel, download

I have a list data in my spring mvc application. I need to generate excel file from this list and then send excel file to browser for download. Which library should I use and how can I use it?
 I want to do this action in spring controller, not in jsp page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it depends how complicated your excel file should be. There are more libraries, I have some experience with [Jasper reports library](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) and I can recommend it. There is a [Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jaspersoft-studio) available, which serves as an GUI editor. You can design a template, etc.

The next option is to do it using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) - the work with that is very straightforward.